# Selenium won't pull hrefs of 8 or more

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape from Linkedin hrefs to better filter the results. However, for some reason the code will only return results 1-7 only. Results 8 or more will not return, even if explicitly stated. I have included sleep timers to help the website complete the load, but still only 1-7. Is there a bug, a security measure or something wrong with the code?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from icecream import ic

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
service = Service(executable_path=PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
user = "*********"
pswd = "***********"

driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/jobs")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
userLogin = driver.find_element('id', "session_key")
pswdLogin = driver.find_element('id', "session_password")
userLogin.send_keys(user)
pswdLogin.send_keys(pswd)
pswdLogin.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
driver.implicitly_wait(600)
searchKey = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[contains(@id, "jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember")]')
searchLocation = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[contains(@id, "jobs-search-box-location-id-ember")]')

searchKey.send_keys("python developer")
searchLocation.send_keys("27560")
time.sleep(0.25)
searchLocation.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
time.sleep(2)
jobs = []
for i in range(1, 16):
   ic(i)
   the_url = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,
                                 value='/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/main/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[' + str(
                                     i) + ']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a')
   print(the_url.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: What makes you think there _are_ more than 7 anchor elements that match your query? I don't see anything in your code that first checks how many element there are, before then iterating over _that_ set. Instead, your code just assumes there are 16 elements.

Comment: Ok, I recode for that.